# How to start searching from second column using grep command

Tags: linux, search, grep, string, egrep

I have a file contains string like the following:

```
site1.com,Level1.2
site2.com,Level1.1,Level1.0,Level1.2
site3.com,Level1.2
site4.com,Level1.2,Level1.1,Level1.0,Levelv3
siteLevel1.2,Levelv2
Level1.2,Levelv2
```

I want to use `grep` to search for a word. I used this command:

```
grep -w "Level1.2" file1.txt > result.txt
```

The output is:

```
site1.com,Level1.2
site2.com,Level1.1,Level1.0,Level1.2
site3.com,Level1.2
site4.com,Level1.2,Level1.1,Level1.0,Levelv3
Level1.2,Levelv2
```

But I need grep to ignore the first column. I need the following in the output:

```
site1.com,Level1.2
site2.com,Level1.1,Level1.0,Level1.2
site3.com,Level1.2
site4.com,Level1.2,Level1.1,Level1.0,Levelv3
```

Please try to help me with my own command as much as possible. I do not prefer new commands and ways for search. I am happy with mine just need to search starting from second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple modification of [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1329100/327367) to your related question:

```
grep '^[^,]*,.*Level1\.2' myfile.txt
```

Or even more simply:

```
grep ',Level1\.2' myfile.txt
```

The preceding comma in the match string ensures that nothing in the first field is matched.

If there's a possibility of `Level1.20` or `Level1.2a`, and you want to exclude these cases, then you need to add a word delimiter:

```
grep ',Level1\.2\b' myfile.txt
```

Note that none of these cases needs `egrep` (or `grep -E`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-P` option (PCRE) with positive lookbehind:

```
grep -Pw "(?<=,)Level1\.2" file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
site1.com,Level1.2
site2.com,Level1.1,Level1.0,Level1.2
site3.com,Level1.2
site4.com,Level1.2,Level1.1,Level1.0,Levelv3
```